chordDiagram() error in number of sectors
I am trying to create a chord diagram using the circlize package, however I am struggling with the circos.par() codes just before creating the plot. I don't think I quite understand my mistakes and how to fix it.
My code below:
#data
subset<- structure(list(from = c("TRBV5-6", "TRBV6-1", "TRAV17", "TRBV14", 
"TRBV7-2", "TRBV15", "TRAV38-1", "TRBV29-1", "TRBV6-5", "TRBV6-6", 
"TRBV28", "TRBV7-8", "TRBV20-1", "TRBV7-8", "TRBV29-1", "TRBV29-1", 
"TRBV9"), to = c("TRAV1-1", "TRAV1-2", "TRAV12-2", "TRAV13-1", 
"TRAV14/DV4", "TRAV17", "TRAV20", "TRAV20", "TRAV25", "TRAV27", 
"TRAV3", "TRAV3", "TRAV38-1", "TRAV38-2/DV8", "TRAV5", "TRAV8-2", 
"TRAV8-2"), value = c(56L, 61L, 66L, 48L, 53L, 67L, 61L, 37L, 
86L, 64L, 38L, 144L, 52L, 56L, 31L, 84L, 188L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-17L))

#creating the chord diagram
circos.clear()
gridcols<- brewer.pal(12,"Paired")
gridcols<- colorRampPalette(gridcols)(length(sort(unique(c(subset$from, subset$to)))))
circos.par(gap.after=c(rep(1,length(unique(subset[[1]]))-1),10,
                       rep(1,length(unique(subset[[2]]))-1),10),
           canvas.xlim = c(-1.5, 1.5), # Adjust x-axis limits for more space
           canvas.ylim = c(-1.5, 1.5))
chordDiagram(subset, grid.col = gridcols,annotationTrack = "grid", preAllocateTracks = 1) #this creates the plot w/o labelling

#add label and axis
circos.trackPlotRegion(track.index = 2, panel.fun = function(x, y) {
xlim = get.cell.meta.data("xlim")
ylim = get.cell.meta.data("ylim")
sector.name = get.cell.meta.data("sector.index")

#print labels
circos.text(mean(xlim), ylim[1] + 2.5, sector.name,
        facing = "clockwise",niceFacing = TRUE, adj = c(0, 0.5), cex = 0.6)

#print axis
circos.axis(h = "top",labels.cex = 0.5,major.tick.length = 0.2,sector.index = sector.name,track.index = 2)
}, bg.border = NA)

I am getting the following error:
Error: Since `gap.degree` parameter has length larger than 1, it should have same length as the number of sectors.

However, when I do not use the circos.par() argument as in the code below, I get the graph:
#data
subset<- structure(list(from = c("TRBV5-6", "TRBV6-1", "TRAV17", "TRBV14", 
"TRBV7-2", "TRBV15", "TRAV38-1", "TRBV29-1", "TRBV6-5", "TRBV6-6", 
"TRBV28", "TRBV7-8", "TRBV20-1", "TRBV7-8", "TRBV29-1", "TRBV29-1", 
"TRBV9"), to = c("TRAV1-1", "TRAV1-2", "TRAV12-2", "TRAV13-1", 
"TRAV14/DV4", "TRAV17", "TRAV20", "TRAV20", "TRAV25", "TRAV27", 
"TRAV3", "TRAV3", "TRAV38-1", "TRAV38-2/DV8", "TRAV5", "TRAV8-2", 
"TRAV8-2"), value = c(56L, 61L, 66L, 48L, 53L, 67L, 61L, 37L, 
86L, 64L, 38L, 144L, 52L, 56L, 31L, 84L, 188L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-17L))

#creating the chord diagram
circos.clear()
gridcols<- brewer.pal(12,"Paired")
gridcols<- colorRampPalette(gridcols)(length(sort(unique(c(subset$from, subset$to)))))

chordDiagram(subset, grid.col = gridcols,annotationTrack = "grid", preAllocateTracks = 1) #this creates the plot w/o labelling

#add label and axis
circos.trackPlotRegion(track.index = 2, panel.fun = function(x, y) {
xlim = get.cell.meta.data("xlim")
ylim = get.cell.meta.data("ylim")
sector.name = get.cell.meta.data("sector.index")

#print labels
circos.text(mean(xlim), ylim[1] + 2.5, sector.name,
        facing = "clockwise",niceFacing = TRUE, adj = c(0, 0.5), cex = 0.6)

#print axis
circos.axis(h = "top",labels.cex = 0.5,major.tick.length = 0.2,sector.index = sector.name,track.index = 2)
}, bg.border = NA)


Two issues with this plot above:

I do not have any gaps between the sectors in the top half and bottom half
The TRAVs and TRBVs are mixed (ideally I want the TRAVs to be at the top and TRBVs at the bottom.

Any help would be much appreciated!

You have TRAV17 and TRAV38-1 in both columns, counting them twice in circos.par. Thus, your gep.degree parameter has length 28, but the number of sectors is 26. This is exactly what the error tells you.
This will correct the error and your first issue:
circos.par(gap.after=c(rep(1,length(unique(subset[[1]]))-3),10, # Remove two extra sectors
                       rep(1,length(unique(subset[[2]]))-1),10),
           canvas.xlim = c(-1.5, 1.5), # Adjust x-axis limits for more space
           canvas.ylim = c(-1.5, 1.5))

For the 2nd issue, you need to rearrange the data before drawing the diagram. For example, with:
subset = subset[order(strtrim(subset$from, 4), decreasing = T),]

UPDATE: Another option to rearrange the sectors without rearranging the data is to use order argument of chordDiagram. For this you can use vector of sector names in the order you need.

Hi @yuk just for my understanding, the -3 aspect in the gap.after argument specifically removes those characters that are present in both columns (like TRAV17 and TRAV38-1)? Which sector is it actually removing? I don't think I quite understand the -1 or -3 aspect like why is it necessary in the first place. If I remove the -1 or -3 entirely, the plot doesn't work either. An understanding would be helpful. Many thanks!

gap.after (or gap.degree, which is the same) specify the gap after each sector. It's just a numeric vector. In your code, you determine the number of unique elements for from and to columns separately. You assign gap=1 for each unique element in a group except the last element (-1), for which you assign gap=10. Since you have 2 overlapping TRAV elements in the 1st column, you need to remove them from the count. This is why to use -3. At the end, the length of the vector for gap.after has to be the same as the number of unique elements in both columns of your data.

Hi @yuk,many thanks. Another question related to this piece of code: If I wanted to code all the TRBVs using the colour palette I chose (the colorRamppalette) and all the TRAVs to be coloured "grey", how would I do that without manually inputting each colour for each sector? Is there a shortcut?

You need to determine the number of unique TRBVs and TRAVs separately. Create corresponding vector of colors as trbv_cols = colorRampPalette(some_set_of_colors)(nTRBV) and trav_cols = rep("grey", nTRAV). Then combine them into one: gridcols = c(trbv_cols, trav_cols).  Something like that.

It's hard to write large piece of code in comments. If you want more details, it would be better to make a new question. But you should have enough to try by yourself first.

Hi @yuk thanks a lot, your suggested piece of code worked!
